# How to know if images are really cached into memory ohs 11.1.1.7 (based on apache 2.2)

Tags: apache, caching

We have configured the module mod_file_cache, example configuration:

```
...
LoadModule file_cache_module "${ORACLE_HOME}/ohs/modules/mod_file_cache.so" 
... 

include "/opt/oraas/appweb/estaticos/media/conf/mmap_media.conf" 
...
```

Example of content of mmap_media.conf:

```
...

MMapFile /opt/oraas/appweb/estaticos/media/img_fmj_cu1.jpg

MMapFile /opt/oraas/appweb/estaticos/media/img_fmj_cu2.jpg 

...
```

The total number of images to be cached is 48100, it is around 3.5 Gbs.

OHS instance takes around 50 seconds in starting, we see memory of server increases and no error in logs but we do not know how to confirm all those images are really cached in memory.

How can we confirm explicitly that those images are cached in memory of the OHS server?